# Wordpress to echo post 4 in a row

Tags: php, wordpress, post, categories

Dear stackoverflow, could someone assist me with this issue since i have spent more that 3 hours trying to fix it. The code below echos 2 post in a row, but i want it to be 4 in a row. 
Thanks for helping:

The first is my **content.php**

```
<article  id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('group'); ?>>   
    <div class="post-inner post-hover">

        <div class="post-thumbnail_id">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
                     <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumb-medium'); ?>
                <?php elseif ( ot_get_option('placeholder') != 'off' ): ?>
                    <img class="placeholder" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/thumb-medium.png" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>

        </div>

    </div>  
</article>
```

**The index.php**

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=content&showposts=2'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <div class="post-list group">
                      <div style="background:green; width:100%;">
            <?php $i = 1; echo '<div class="post-row2">'; while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
          <?php get_template_part('content'); ?>
            <?php if($i % 2 == 0) {echo '</div><div class="post-row2"></div><div class="post-row2">'; 

            } 
          $i++; endwhile; echo '</div>'; ?>

    </div></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: have you tried changing every occurrence of 2 to 4? small clue:category_name=content&showposts=4

Comment: Yeah , but no success:


  <?php query_posts('category_name=brand-identity&showposts=4'); ?>
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
  
   <div class="post-list group">
    
    
    <?php $i = 1; echo '<div class="post-row2">'; while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('identity_content'); ?>
    <?php if($i % 4 == 0) { echo '</div><div class="post-row2">'; } $i++; endwhile; echo '</div>'; ?>
    
   
   </div>
 
  <?php endif; ?>

Comment: have you got 4 posts?

Comment: yes i have have 4 post

Comment: are they in the right category? e.g. 'content'

Comment: Yes... Rhys idea was geat.... But i needed to do some changes.. to take all the divs from the content.php and use one div in the index.

Comment: Mmmm,. on Modlies, they are not responsive since the images have been given 23%... Better 100

Comment: I will like the 4 to be on a row on desktop, which is now fine but i will appreciate 2 rows on mobile scale.

Answer (score 1):

Change the first line of your index.php to:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=content&showposts=4'); ?>
```

Comment: i did but still had 2 on a row

Comment: Can you tell me why do you use this part $i % 2 == 0 ? If you input 4 posts you`ll only display two with this condition

Comment: took it out, but still did not work.. this way:<?php if($i == 0) { echo '</div><div class="post-row">'; } $i++; endwhile; echo '</div>'; ?>

Comment: Ah got it @Rhys Stewart is correct change $i % 2 to $i % 4 and providing you have enough posts it will put the end of the row after the fourth so try if($i % 4 == 0) {

Comment: Also this code seems a little flawed in a way that if a the number of posts is not divisible by 4 you'll get one unclosed <div> if i'm correct

Comment: Rather no sucess, still 2 up 2 down

Answer (score 1):

The content.php doesn't show any reference to the amount of posts it can load in so i cant try and get a fix for that. I can try and do soemthing for the index.php though.

Try this out:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=brand-identity&showposts=4'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div class="post-list group">
                  <div style="background:green; width:100%;">
        <?php $i = 1; echo '<div class="post-row4">'; while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>
      <?php get_template_part('identity_content'); ?>
        <?php if($i % 4 == 0) {echo '</div><div class="post-row4"></div><div class="post-row4">'; 

        } 
      $i++; endwhile; echo '</div>'; ?>

</div></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You need to not only make the `showposts=4` but also make sure that the html is also done to allow 4 columns. Since you already have `post-row2`, i would guess that `post-row4` is available for a 4 column layout.

If post-row4 is not setup, we'll need a little bit of CSS. but try the code above out first.

## EDIT

Add this to your `CSS`

```
.post-row4 {
    width: 23.5%;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
.post-row4:nth-child(4n+4) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Should allow 4 elements to be in a row and fit into in space.

Comment: it actually does show a reference to the amount of posts it can load
`<?php query_posts('category_name=content&showposts=2'); ?>`

Comment: Please there is no post-row4, i simply set post-row to custom this code:
this is the CSS:


    .post-list .post-row2 { margin-left: -30px; padding-left: 30px; float: left; width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; margin-bottom: 30px; position: relative;padding-top: 30px; }
.post-list .post-row2:last-child { border: none; margin-bottom: 0; }
.identity-list .post-row2 { margin-left: -30px; padding-left: 30px; float: left; width: 23%; border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; margin-bottom: 30px; position: relative;padding-top: 30px; }

Comment: sure... i am not sure if i can post it here

Comment: i need 10 reputations to post images

Comment: Thanks Rhys, i have posted the image

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by taking CSS proposal by Rhys.  One or two things still to fix, but i have all the 4 on one row. Thanks everyone for your assistance.